# Can you use two IDs to select with in CSS? #content.special #page

Tags: css

I've search through about 10 pages, can't find this question here. I'm trying to ask what should be a simple question, but I'd like to know if there is a way to select the second ID conditionally in CSS.

Here is the gist of it:

```
#container {width:1000px;}
#page {width:600px;}
#sidebar {width:400px;}

#container.special {width:800px}
#container.special #sidebar {width:200px;}
```

Basically, if the container has the class `special`, it shrinks and therefor the divs inside would need to adjust as well.

I thought this would work, but it doesn't seem to. I can fix this many different ways and this is only an example, so I'm not trying to fix anything, just understand if it is possible and if not, if there is a CSS solution.

Thanks,
Exit

Comment: what's your HTML look like? I don't see why this wouldn't work.

Comment: Your title mentions `#content.special #page` but that selector doesn't appear in the sample CSS.  Mistake or intentional?

Comment: If it is possible (which I would think it would be) then I must have a CSS clash somewhere. I'm just trying to determine if it is valid or not before burning hours on a stupid little thing.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the code is in the title, just the question of using two IDs to define an area.

Comment: Then why put specific IDs in the title that conflict with the content of your question?

Comment: To provide an example, much like seeing foo functions.

Comment: The problem why it wasn't working is mostly due to me being overtired and overworked as I've been churning out projects like mad. This conflict came at the end of my day and it was a really stupid mistake on my part. In essence, to use the example above, sidebar was *not* in container and therefore could not be affected by what I was trying. Oh, my tired eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is valid CSS. Your rule for `#container.special #sidebar` will override the `#sidebar` rule (since it's more specific), and the sidebar should get smaller.

If it's not taking effect, try using Firebug to inspect the #sidebar element. It will show you what specific style rules are actually getting applied. Then at least you'll know which rule is conflicting and we can help figure out why.

Comment: Thought so, I haven't upgraded Firefox to 3.5 yet, so I can't run Firebug yet. I have a feeling it will make life much easier when I do.